# Unable to do Pop menu

Tags: android

I have been trying to do such a pop up menu. However, I am not able to do it since I can not put pictures and give design in pop-up menu. Does any one know to do such a pop menu?

[image]

Comment: Actually, i was going to add its picture but since i have no reputation higher than 10, it could not allow me to add picture

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html). I hope this will help you achieving what you want.

An example for pop up menu is [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example).

**EDIT**
Create an `PopUpWindow` layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llSortChangePopup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/sort_popup_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/distance"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sort_popup_devider" 
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/sort_popup_devider"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPriority"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/priority"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="popupSortOnClick"
    android:textColor="@color/my_black" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sort_popup_devider" 
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/sort_popup_devider"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/time"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="popupSortOnClick"
    android:textColor="@color/my_black" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sort_popup_devider" 
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/sort_popup_devider"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/status"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/my_black" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="popupSortOnClick"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

and then create the `PopUpWindow` in your Activity:

```
// The method that displays the popup.
private void showStatusPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {



    // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
       LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.llStatusChangePopup);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.status_popup_layout, null);

       // Creating the PopupWindow
       changeStatusPopUp = new PopupWindow(context);
       changeStatusPopUp.setContentView(layout);
       changeStatusPopUp.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       changeStatusPopUp.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       changeStatusPopUp.setFocusable(true);

       // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the left, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
       int OFFSET_X = -20;
       int OFFSET_Y = 50;

       //Clear the default translucent background
       changeStatusPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

       // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
       changeStatusPopUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
    }
```

finally pop it it up `onClick` of a button or anything else:

```
imTaskStatusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 int[] location = new int[2];
                 currentRowId = position;
                 currentRow = v;    
                 // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
                 // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
                 v.getLocationOnScreen(location);

                 //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
                 point = new Point();
                 point.x = location[0];
                 point.y = location[1];
                 showStatusPopup(TasksListActivity.this, point);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, i have seen this, and some other tutorials. However, i could not find answers. How can i add icons and give design